# Using Process Builder, how to plug data from Account record into custom object field

Tags: process-builder

Data to grab:  Account -> AccountNumber
Field to update:  Issue(custom object) -> AccountNr
RecordID of Account is contained in Issue(custom object) -> AccountName

What type of field should Issue -> AccountNr be?
What are the steps necessary to accomplish this update?

Comment: Could there be multiple issues for each account?

Comment: See Trailhead for Process Builder; [AccountNumber is a Text field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm?search_text=accountnumber)